# How to pass data between jquery click events

Tags: jquery, function, events, parameters

I have a select change click event that captures data that I need to be passed to another click event. Is there a way I can do this? Here's my pseudo-code:

Select change event:

```
$(".item_status").change(function() {

    //I want to pass data stored in my order_status variable to my save_info click event below
    var order_status = $('option:selected',this).text();


    //now open a modal
    $("#my_modal").modal('toggle');

});

$("#save_info").click(function() {
    //This save_info button is inside of my my_modal modal
    //I want to use the order_status variable defined in the change event above:
    console.log(order_status);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it but I think this would work:

```
$(".item_status").change(function() {

    //I want to pass data stored in my order_status variable to my save_info click event below
    var order_status = $('option:selected',this).text();


    $("#save_info").data("order_status", order_status);


    //now open a modal
    $("#my_modal").modal('toggle');

});

$("#save_info").click(function() {
    //This save_info button is inside of my my_modal modal
    //I want to use the order_status variable defined in the change event above:
    console.log($(this).data("order_status"));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable outside of the function.

```
var order_status;

$(".item_status").change(function() {

    order_status = $('option:selected',this).text();

    $("#my_modal").modal('toggle');

});

$("#save_info").click(function() {

    if (!order_status) return;

    console.log(order_status);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! - to confirm, the variable will "go away" once the page refreshes, right?

Comment: Yes :) When you refresh, all the scripts on your page are executed from the start and so your variables are reset.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to save that variable globally, so that it accessible by other functions. For example:

```
var order_status = null; // Initialize global variable. 

//** On Item Status Change **//
$(".item_status").change(function() {

  // I want to pass data stored in my order_status variable to my save_info click event below
  order_status = $('option:selected',this).text();

  //now open a modal
  $("#my_modal").modal('toggle');
});

//** On Save Info Click **//
$("#save_info").click(function() {
  // This save_info button is inside of my my_modal modal
  // I want to use the order_status variable defined in the change event above:
  console.log(order_status);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Using the almost same call has in change event :

```
$("#save_info").click(function() {
    var order_status = $(".item_status").children('option:selected').text();
    //This save_info button is inside of my my_modal modal
    //I want to use the order_status variable defined in the change event above:
    console.log(order_status);
});
```

### Solution 2

Wrap the whole thing in a function :

```
(function() {

    var order_status = "";

    $(".item_status").change(function() {

        //I want to pass data stored in my order_status variable to my save_info click event below
        order_status = $('option:selected',this).text();

        //now open a modal
        $("#my_modal").modal('toggle');
    });

    $("#save_info").click(function() {
        //This save_info button is inside of my my_modal modal
        //I want to use the order_status variable defined in the change event above:
        console.log(order_status);
    });

})();
```